# Should there be a separate tag for One D&D?

Tags: discussion, tags, dnd-5e, dungeons-and-dragons

Yesterday, Wizards of the Coast announced the playtest material for its next iteration of D&D, codenamed [One D&D](https://www.dndbeyond.com/one-dnd). Later that day, they released the first Unearthed Arcana document with part of the new ruleset: [Character Origins](https://media.dndbeyond.com/compendium-images/one-dnd/character-origins/CSWCVV0M4B6vX6E1/UA2022-CharacterOrigins.pdf?icid_source=house-ads&icid_medium=crosspromo&icid_campaign=playtest1).

Where it gets complicated is that while this is playtest material for a new iteration, it is backward-compatible with all 5e products, as confirmed on yesterday's [stream](https://www.twitch.tv/magic). The existing tag [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) is of course relevant, but should there be a new tag (e.g. `one-dnd`) to specify that a question pertains to the new playtest ruleset?

Answer (score 37):

I [suggested in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/61816795#61816795) that we use [one-dnd-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-dnd-playtest), similar to the tags we used for the 5e and PF 2e playtests, [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) and [pathfinder-2e-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pathfinder-2e-playtest).

Questions strictly about the playtest material would not need [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e), but questions about the interaction between playtest material and 5e material should get both tags. In the case that we see two system tags creating something of a tag burden, e.g. the question really needs four non-system tags, we can reevaluate those particular questions to see what works best in each case.

Comment: I agreed in chat and I agree here.

Comment: I particularly agree that [*-playtest] would be good here, as WotC has called 'One D&D' its "codename" for the playtest of D&D's next evolution. Who knows whether 'One' will go the way of 'Next'?

Answer (score 24):

Writing a separate answer to keep voting for this proposal separate from the other.

#### Keep [one-dnd-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-dnd-playtest) separate from Unearthed Arcana content written for 5e

This one seems pretty straightforward, but I want to leave it here for confirmation via vote anyway. It seems quite plain that *the One D&D playtest content is of a different substance than Unearthed Arcana content for 5th Edition*. While the new playtest material is being referred to as Unearthed Arcana, it seems like a good idea to keep this next generation content distinct.

This would mean *not* using [unearthed-arcana](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unearthed-arcana) for One D&D content, unless, of course, the question was about the interaction between One D&D content and 5e Unearthed Arcana.

Comment: +1 Because I don't want every single [tag:one-dnd-playtest] question to mandatorily also have [tag:unearthed-arcana], which would take up 2 of the 5 tag slots

Comment: Agree with Except-Medic. If we commit to using the one-dnd-playtest tag for any question related to One D&D, then having a 2nd tag be mandatory on 100% of such questions isn't adding any useful information, and is taking up another tag slot (for a total of 3 if the dnd-5e tag is also used).

Comment: That said, maybe the tag descriptions for one-dnd-playtest and unearthed-arcana should explain the distinction to help people choose the correct tag?

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson Yes, I haven’t looked at tag descriptions yet, but I’ll work on that soon.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I wrote a description for the [one-dnd-playtest] tag that addresses this. (It needs an edit, but I think it's in the right direction.)

Comment: @GuybrushMcKenzie Yep, I approved it, looks good for now.

Answer (score 6):

### [one-dnd-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-dnd-playtest) is not necessarily [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e)

We have a few old [dnd-next-playtest](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-next-playtest) questions, which became [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) eventually. The systems used in both were quite different at times. one-dnd[-playtest] is the next evolution of it on the way to [dnd-6e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-6e) or whatever they will assign as the next edition's name. **So we should give it (or its playtest) its own tag.**

In fact, I bet that in the future often the One-D&D[-playtest] questions should **not** have either [dnd-5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-5e) or [unearthed-arcana](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unearthed-arcana) tag, as they are an ecosystem on their own, even if in flux and development. Once we have a sufficient... *branch* from the previous edition, we also shouldn't tag it that way!

Comment: Note that the designers have stated that they're moving away from a numbered edition system to just calling it "D&D". ([See this FAQ on D&D Beyond.](https://www.dndbeyond.com/posts/1310-faq-one-d-d-rules-d-d-digital-and-physical-digital)) So even when the One D&D playtest content is finalized/officially released, it's not going to be called "6th edition". (That doesn't invalidate the rest of your recommendation, though.)

Comment: @V2Blast they might not call it 6th edition but add a variant to it - they want to overhaul it again in about 10 years.

Comment: @V2Blast it may not be called "6th edition" by anyone at WotC, but I'll definitely refer to it among friends as [14th edition](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/343/23970) =)

Answer (score -3):

I think it would be good to have a one-dnd tag as well as a one-dnd-playtest tag the same way we have a dnd-next-playtest and a dnd-5e tag, or a pf-2e-playtest and pf-2e tag. People are already getting confused between the two so being able to separate the two out would help stop the confusion. It's no replacement for editing questions to change "in one D&D blah blah" to "in the Character Origins UA blah blah", but it helps.

Comment: We cannot have a tag with no questions, so we cannot have a tag for the new official rule set until we have questions about it.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I think you can right? Unless I'm missing something I don't see anything stopping me creating the tag? What do you mean?

Comment: Tags without questions are deleted.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov Oh, we can't override it? Weird that it lets you make them

Comment: We can't make tags that don't belong to a question; the only way to make new tags is by applying them to a question.

Comment: Currently, one-dnd is **only** the playtest and it has one document. So we only have one-dnd-playtest questions.

Comment: @Trish one-dnd isn't only the playtest, it's the code name for the next version. Here's an example of someone answering a playtest question with a final version answer: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/revisions/201093/1 In this question I clarified with the OP that they were asking about the playtest, not the final version, and the answer has been updated. You can still see comments about it.

Comment: The OP of this question expressed that they couldn't ask about one-dnd because there was no tag (seeming to imply that the lack of tag makes it a banned topic). This seems to be a fairly common concept, so it's something we should be aware of. If it's just a technical limitation then that sucks, it might be worth asking a one-dnd question just to get it done so the site can function?

Comment: “it might be worth asking a one-dnd question just to get it done so the site can function?” The site is not malfunctioning, and that is not an appropriate use of questions and tags.

Comment: @user77842 older users can easily fix a mistagging.

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I'm talking about the confusion between the playtest and final release.

Comment: @user77842 While we do use tags to identify the game system a question is about, *it is the responsibility of the question author to provide sufficient detail for answering the question*, and there is nothing about the tag system preventing or hindering them from doing that because they can just tell us in the body of the question. If a question is unclear to you, ask the author to clarify. Creating a fake question so that a tag can exist isn’t going to help anyone clarify anything or make anyone less confused.